# Create Batch-Mulesoft-Salesforce connector

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to add batches to a job using SFDC Create Batch connector.As per the documentation,it expects jobInfo object(com. sforce. async. JobInfo).Below is the payload that i am sending.Even though i typecast the object to JobInfo object,it still complains
**Message             : "Unable to convert `Array` to class 'org.mule.extension.salesforce.api.bulk.JobInfo'**

I am not sure what i am missing

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var arr = []

---

({

id: "75023000002VC0rAAG" 
}  as Object {
class : "com.sforce.async.JobInfo"
})>> arr
```

Comment: The error clearly shows that it is receiving and array but it expects an object that can be interpreted as job info data of the connector. Usually that is done by creating a plain object with the right attributes. You are using a Salesforce SDK specific class, and then putting it inside an array. The connector doesn't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the sample code you can use.

```
<flow name="AccountAddressFlowFlow" doc:id="d164048e-ab84-42d2-b1bf-cbcdc6c8802a" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="73736cd1-cc6f-425d-8a9e-b2dacb4fd1e4" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/accountaddress"/>
        <file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="9bc9edf9-07af-4061-8d6c-c85eb254d113" path="./AccountAddress/testl2Address.csv" outputMimeType='application/csv; quote="\""; separator=|'>
            <ee:repeatable-file-store-stream bufferUnit="MB" />
        </file:read>
        <salesforce:create-job operation="upsert" type="Account_Address__c" doc:name="Create job" doc:id="6eaef36f-719a-45c6-a4f1-e3897c85dc97" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" target="JobInfo">
            <salesforce:create-job-request ><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    externalIdFieldName: "ADDR_Key__c",
    contentType: "JSON",
    concurrencyMode: "Parallel"
}]]]></salesforce:create-job-request>
        </salesforce:create-job>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="3d6b1820-95bb-4f11-b777-6db7a79319e2" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <batch:job jobName="AccountAddressFlowBatch_Job" doc:id="259c9a9a-72d2-4b46-85cd-6c700fe2e9f5" maxFailedRecords="-1" blockSize="10000" maxConcurrency="16">
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="d5599f4a-0200-410f-95a3-9a38a08173f8" >
                    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="245af51b-1ae7-4958-b644-f45baf7c63dd" >
                        <ee:message >
                            <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    Name:payload.Location_Name80,
    Location_ID__c:payload.Location_ID,
    Fiber_Status__c:payload.fiber_status,
    Account__r:{
            Sub_Account_ID__c:payload.Sub_Account_ID
            },
    Address_Type__c:payload.Address_Type,
    Postal_Code__c:payload.Postal_Code,
    FirstNet_Type__c:payload.FirstNet_Type
}]]></ee:set-payload>
                        </ee:message>
                    </ee:transform>
                    <batch:aggregator doc:name="Batch Aggregator" doc:id="33855357-eb2d-4dd3-ade2-ce043530665e" size="10000">
                        <salesforce:create-batch doc:name="Create batch" doc:id="83d9ab61-50dd-469b-bbf8-d2f53f36b3bc" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" jobInfoBatch="#[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
vars.JobInfo]"/>
                    </batch:aggregator>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="b1c1fc2d-a3f4-4bf1-8ceb-5f249df58c60" />
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="e2bd3d39-2fc9-46f6-a686-55531f77a2d6" message="Account Address Completed"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```